# password protecting a website

Tags: php, html, windows

I am looking at quickly password protecting a website, one folder on a server. I have played around with `.htaccess` and just realised that it's probably not working because it's likely it's sat on a windows server running PHP. I'am assumming this also means I can't use authenticate in PHP. Does any have any suggestions on a simple proctect I can implement in this scenario ? Thanks.

Comment: I meant .htaccess :)

Comment: What webserver software are you using? (IIS? Apache? Something else?)

Comment: Hi, I'm told it's IIS (I'm locked out from that)

Comment: check out SF: http://serverfault.com/questions/79034/how-to-simulate-htaccess-for-auth-with-iis-without-having-access-to-the-server-co

Comment: Thanks, think I may go down the route of building / using a PHP login script.

Answer (score 1):

[Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is not OS-specific. It's part of the HTTP standard, but the implementation details are webserver specific. `.htaccess` is how the Apacheweb server implements this (and other features). If you can do other things (like URL rewriting) via `.htaccess`, then authentication should also work. If not, you have to find out what webserver you're using ([probably IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/abbca505-6f63-4267-aac1-1ea89d861eb4.mspx)) and how to configure basic auth there.

Comment: Hmm, found out the hosting is with fasthosts - I can get into the panel but they charge for being able to configure basic auth. Is there anything I can do in PHP to achieve the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to solve the problem in PHP solely, you could set a 'landing' page that requires a login or just password entry. Set up a cookie to store that information, then have each page check for the cookie. That's the way I would do it if I couldn't change the .htaccess file or wanted a PHP-only solution.

Comment: Cheers, that sounds like a plan.

Comment: note that this doesn't protect access from non-HTML/PHP files in your folder. You might want to move such files to a folder outside the webroot and forward them via a PHP site protected as Saladin describes it.

Comment: @nicolas78 Good point there. I didn't think of non-HTML/PHP content.